# DGET with array constant as criteria parameter with a blank element

Tags: google-sheets

If I have the following table:

```
 \ || A  |  B  |  C  |  D  |  E  |  F  |
 _______________________________________
 1 || H1 | H2  | H3  | H4  | 10  | 20  |
 2 || 10 | AA  | .2  | 70  | 70  | 100 |
 3 || 10 | BB  | .3  | 80  |     |     |
 4 || 20 | CC  | .4  | 90  |     | 10  |
 5 || 20 | DD  | .5  | 100 |     | CC  |
 6 ||    |     |     |     |     |     |
```

(*All workings examples are in Google Docs)

This works:

```
 =DGET(A1:D5,"H3",{A1:D1;E1,E3,E4,E2}) 
 RESULT = 0.2
```

But I'm looking for a way to have a blank element in the constant array I'm using as the criteria without referencing a blank cell. I need the blank elements as otherwise DGET treats them as criteria to be evaluated.

Something like this:

```
 =DGET(A1:D5,"H4",{A1:D1;E1,#BLANK,#BLANK,E2})
```

Where #BLANK is whatever magic makes google docs treat the element as empty.

I know that I can do:

```
 =DGET(A1:D5,"H3",{A1,D1;E1,E2})
```

And just limit the number of columns in the criteria, but I'd like to specify the entire header set in the constant and just choose the columns I want specified.
For instance if I wanted something like this:

```
 =DGET(A1:D5,"H3",{A1:D1;F1,F3,F3,F2;F4,F5,F3,F3})
 RESULT = 0.5
```

But as this:

```
 =DGET(A1:D5,"H3",{A1:D1;F1,#BLANK,#BLANK,F2;F4,F5,#BLANK,#BLANK})
```

In addition to the primary question of how to set an empty element, I'm curious if there is a way to perform a similar lookup in Excel. LOOKUP functions do not appear to support filtering on multiple criteria and the Database functions don't support arrays for defining criteria (only a cell range).

Comment: Can you clarify if this is for Excel or Google Sheets? If Excel, can you confirm in which version your first formula, i.e. =DGET(A1:D5,"H3",{A1:D1;E1,E3,E4,E2}), "works", as you put it? That syntax is invalid in all versions of Excel as far as I know.

Comment: It was only tested in Docs. You are right, just tested it in Excel and apparently Excel does not support constant arrays as a criteria for DGET. It also does not appear to like creating constant arrays with cell references. (Didn't realize that Docs was implementing these functions differently). I will edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the `#BLANK` you're looking for is:

```
  ""
```

And, No. Excel does not support such sophisticated arrays.

Comment: If this helped, click ☑ on the left of this post